# R: Understanding how object.size() relates to memory use

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, ggplot2

I have run a number of analyses and saved all the 24x8 ggplots into a list.

When I inspect the object size I get:

```
print(object.size(output_list), units = "Mb")
115.3 Mb
```

If I save the object as a rds-file the object takes up around 650 Mb.

If I inspect the memory use of the object I get:

```
library(pryr)
mem_used() # Note: In example I only have this object in the R memory
28.2 GB
```

I am not sure why I get these HUGE difference in sizes, and I have not been able to find a clear explaination on the webs yet. Can you help me understand why this seemingly small object takes up so much of the memory?

I have an idea that it is because all the plots store all data points in their plotData? But wouldn't that also affect the object.size? I also considered that it is due to the tree structure, as e.g. in the data.tree package each note saves an individual environment.

Comment: The function `mem_used()` returns the total amount of memory used by R, is `output_list` the only object in your R session?

Answer (score 2):

As per help, `mem_used` sums the Ncells and Vcells -- *Vcells (memory used by vectors) and Ncells (memory used by everything else)*).

This seems to work fine on my laptop.

Best to do `gc()` as well to get a better idea.

```
rm(list = ls())
m <- 1:100000000

object_size(m)
#400 MB

mem_used()
#454 MB

gc()
#           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used  (Mb)
#Ncells   753450  40.3    1442291  77.1   1442291  77.1
#Vcells 51417867 392.3  121970165 930.6 101419240 773.8
```